# Client-side templating frameworks to streamline using jQuery with REST/JSON

Tags: json, rest, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm starting to migrate some html generation tasks from a server-side framework to the client.  I'm using jQuery on the client. My goal is to get JSON data via a REST api and use this data to populate HTML into the page.

Right now, when a user on my site clicks a link to **My Projects**, the server generates HTML like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Clean Toilet</dt>
    <dd>Get off your butt and clean this filth!</dd>

    <dt>Clean Car</dt>
    <dd>I think there's something growing in there...</dd>

    <dt>Replace Puked on Baby Sheets</dt>
</dl>
```

I'm changing this so that clicking **My Projects** will now do a GET request that returns something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Clean Car",
    "description":"I think there's something growing in there..."
  },
  {
    "name":"Clean Toilets",
    "description":"Get off your butt and clean this filth!"
  },
  {
    "name":"Replace Puked on Baby Sheets"
  }
]
```

I can certainly write custom jQuery code to take that JSON and generate the HTML from it. This is not my question, and I don't need advice on how to do that.

What I'd like to do is completely separate the presentation and layout from the logic (jquery code). I don't want to be creating DL, DT, and DD elements via jQuery code. I'd rather use some sort of HTML templates that I can fill the data in to. These templates could simply be HTML snippets that are hidden in the page that the application was loaded from. Or they could be dynamically loaded from the server (to support user specific layouts, i18n, etc.). They could be displayed a single time, as well as allow looping and repeating. Perhaps it should support sub-templates, if/then/else, and so forth.

I have LOTS of lists and content on my site that are presented in many different ways. I'm looking to create a simple and consistent way to generate and display content without creating custom jQuery code for every different feature on my site. To me, this means I need to find or build a small framework on top of jQuery (probably as a plugin) that meets these requirements.

The only sort of framework that I've found that is anything like this is [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/).  I don't know how good it is, as I haven't used it yet. At first glance, I'm not thrilled by it's template syntax.

Anyone know of other frameworks or plugins that I should look into? Any blog posts or other resources out there that discuss doing this sort of thing?  I just want to make sure that I've surveyed everything out there before building it myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since posting this question, I have found many other templating options. I've listed many of them below. However, there was recently a [jQuery templates proposal](https://github.com/nje/jquery/wiki/jquery-templates-proposal) that may be the most promising solution yet. There is also a [discussion about it](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-templates-proposal) on the jquery site.  Here is the project location:

- https://github.com/nje/jquery/wiki/jquery-templates-proposal

Other solutions I've come across include (in no particular order):

- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/509108.aspx
- http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/
- http://beebole.com/pure/
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jTemplates
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/advancedmerge
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tempest
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jBind
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/cliche
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/appendDom
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/openSocial-jquery-templates
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Orange-J
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/fromTemplate-microtemplate
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/resiglet
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/databind
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jsont
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/domplate
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/noTemplate
- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryHtmlTemplates
- http://github.com/trix/nano
- http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/chainjs-jquery-data-binding-service
- http://ajaxpatterns.org/Browser-Side_Templating
- http://beebole.com/pure/
- http://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/
- http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates
- http://embeddedjs.com/
- [Javascript template system - PURE, EJS, jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869726/javascript-template-system-pure-ejs-jquery-plugin)
- [jQuery templating engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines)
- http://goessner.net/articles/jsont/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want sammy.js

http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/

The tutorials there demo use of the template engine

Comment: Thanks! I've heard of sammy but hadn't looked into it yet. Didn't realize it does templating too.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've used jTemplates quite a few times and from my experience it serves its intended purpose.

If we're limiting the discussion to client side then this is my final comment on the matter as it does the job and despite some funky syntax does it well, however on the server side of things I would definitely prefer the scenario where you POST some JSON which is deserialized to an in-memory object and then validated and passed to a server-side template (such as an ASCX in ASP.NET) where you have the full power of that language.

In my opinion, if the client supports JavaScript well enough for you to be considering jTemplates then I would recommend setting yourself up a JavaScript utility method which allows you to send JSON and receive HTML, thereby cutting out the potentially troublesome middle man.  Most languages have JSON-parsing ability and jQuery can auto-parse a server response into JSON by specifying the return type as "json".

Even if you don't receive the JSON from the JavaScript, you can still take the JSON that you would have sent back to the browser and just send it through your server-side template instead.  In ASP.NET (with MVC for example) you can have strongly-typed template files that do not need to be compiled, making changes a lot easier to implement.  Therefore you would still be sending back markup, but it would have been run through a proper template with the full strength of a programming language behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective, but in my case the point is to move away from server-side generation of HTML. Each item of data has lots of properties, and all the HTML required to wrap all of these properties significantly increases the size of the response.  When I multiply that by hundreds of data elements, my HTML response can be many times larger than the raw data itself. Since my application uses ajax and requires javascript, why not just render it in the browser?

Comment: If there are hundreds of data items, the performance of JavaScript rendering the markup will be far worse than that of a server-side language such as C# or PHP.  Combine this with gzip and AJAX caching and it's not really an issue anymore.  Unless you're really concerned about CPU time in 2010 then there's no real reason to put the burden on the visitor and increase rendering time.

Comment: Rendering time and bandwidth aren't my only reasons for going this direction. However, any non-ancient computer with a recent browser shouldn't be too burdened with the task I have in mind.  Are you implying that the jqGrid control (http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) will take longer overall to download and render 1000 rows of data retrieved via JSON/REST than it would to download already formatted HTML and replaced the grid's innerHTML with it?  I'm sure either way is pretty negligible.

Comment: I'd say it's negligible up to a point, but the difference between JavaScript and C# iterating a collection is huge.  In a case such as jqGrid I would say it's more efficient to pass back some simple TR elements than to make your server serialize every property of an object to JSON and send the whole dataset over.  With the markup method not only is your server only accessing the fields it needs for the grid but the client is only downloading the fields it needs to display.