# Designing user interface for android

Tags: android, user-interface

I don't know whether I should ask this question here. I have very little experience in development of android application. I did few researches. Let me explain my problem. I am making an android app to show a details of a university. I used a **`WebView`** to display the results from a HTML & CSS page it was very easy for me [here](http://dibyaranjan.net76.net/action.php?reg=090101CSR001) is a demo. I thought of using **`JSON`** for fetching data form the database. Now I am not sure how to populate it. Please suggest me a way to populate the same data as in that example page.

I have visited http://android.stackoverflow.com but in FAQs I found this question shouldn't be asked there. I hope I am asking it in the right place.

Comment: If you just want to display the data, without doing any operation then the WebView will do.

Comment: I will save only a single row in SQLite database hence I have to go beyond `WebView`

Comment: Then you will have to use sqlite database in android. You may also have to parse the data before saving it to database.

Comment: For parsing I am using JSON ofcourse PHP too,

Comment: Then you can just show your data in the ListView using custom Adapter by fetching data from database using cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a **simple** solution with **low amount of data** you might also consider to create a pure mobile web-application using a **JavaScript based template systems**. It would suffice as an *pragmatic approach*.

The templates also provide flexibility at later points during your development cycle when you may switch the underlying software-platform (for instance from a web to a native app)

I recommend *PURE* or *handlebars*.

**See**

- [Overview of client-side web templating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system#Client-Side_Systems)
- [Embedded.JS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) (Simple and ultra-fast templating tool to generate HTML from JSON data")
- stackoverflow: [Javascript template system - PURE, EJS, jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869726/javascript-template-system-pure-ejs-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

You can populate your data using `Listview`. You can use a `custom or default adapter` for setting it in the ListView. And you don't need to use `JSON` for fetching data from database. You can fetch data from database using `Cursor`.

Comment: Will you please give me few links where I can see the user interface. I will follow the design pattern. I have no idea about `Cursor`. It would be helpful if you provide few more details about it too.

Comment: You can refer the developer.android.com for any queries. And if you want to learn more about display the data in listview then here is the link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/                                                     http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html